# How do I perform a parallel reduce operation on a recursive structure in Clojure?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, tree, memoization

I'm presented with a tree data structure that I want to process or "evaluate" using a post-walk. There are two exploitable features to the problem:

1. Disjoint subtrees can be processed independently
2. Processing the same sub-tree always yields the same result, so partial results can be memoized (even between workers if possible)

One constraint is that the number of sub-trees may be quite large so I can't spawn a new thread for every sub-tree willy-nilly. Is there any library support that anticipates such a scenario?

Comment: [`core.async`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async) and [`core.reducers`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.reducers) come to mind, but I'm not entirely sure which, if either, would be useful here.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the approximate height of your tree, on average? Also, do you expect them to be relatively balanced? Just getting an idea of the shape of the data.

Comment: The instances I care about might have heights in the hundreds. And I don't expect it to very balanced.